# Assign a Value to a Div so I can keep track of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating and appending images (divs) like this:

```
$('#event_list_main').append('<img class="listed_event" id="random_event" src="final_tutorial_buttons/random.png" height="50" width="50" onclick="one_band_event_action();" />');
```

so each time this is executed, an image pops up next to the previous one and so on! The problem is that I want to keep track of these!

I came accross this

> http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=147935

but I don't know how to implement it. Another thing I thought of is, to pass a reference number (something like a counter) in "append()"
like this:

```
$('#event_list_main').append('<img class="listed_event" id="random_event <INSERT REFERENCE>" src="final_tutorial_buttons/random.png" height="50" width="50" onclick="one_band_event_action();" />');
```

but how can I pass it? is there an escape symbol?

Comment: Please define "keep track of these". F.ex if you want to know how many times the append method has executed, just increment a counter each time after the execution.

Comment: show more of how they are being added, if there is a loop involved makes index easy to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you by "keep track of these" mean that you would like to be able to find a specific image after several appends, you can use the HTML5 data attribute, f.ex:

```
var i = 0;
$('#event_list_main').append('<img data-count="'+(i++)+'">');
```

Then access a single image like:

```
$('#event_list_main').find('img').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('count') == 1;
});
```

Or even better: save them in an array:

```
var images = [];

// inside the loop:

images.push(
    $('<img>', {
        'src': 'image.jpg',
        'class': 'listed_event' // etc
    }).appendTo('#event_list_main')
);
```

Then just access it via the `images` array:

```
images[2]; // the third image
```

Comment: this is more want I want to do. For example I can have 3 "random_events", that are the same color, but I want to remove or access the 3rd one!. I know this sounds kinda strange

Comment: I dont get the syntax //data-count="'+(i++)+'">'//. I already have a variable called counter. so will //data-count="'counter'">'// work? or will it be registered as a string "counter" ?

Comment: You need to add it as a variable: `data-count="'+counter+'"`

Answer (score 0):

Since your new `<img>` tags all have an `id` [attribute that starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `random_event`, you don't need to keep track of them separately. You can just use that selector to get them back at any time:

```
$('#event_list_main').find('img[id^="random_event"]');
```

The above selector can be used to find out how many you've added if you needed to, and iterate over them with `.each()` for any other operation you may want.